# How to override the DCB attributes in SFTP with phpseclib

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I've a [link](https://dovetail.com/docs/sftp/using.html) where I saw the reference to change the default attributes & set the required mode to transfer the dataset through SFTP.

Here is how it is..

```
sftp> ls /+mode=text,lrecl=80,recfm=fb
```

In this, we change the mode to text (where default is the `binary` mode).

When I execute this through command prompt it works fine and gives the same response which means the command executed perfectly!

(Response after executing in command prompt)

```
sftp> ls /+mode=text,lrecl=80,recfm=fb
/+mode=text,lrecl=80,recfm=fb
```

But if I try to use the same through the PHP code it throws me the error as

> ls: FSUM6785 File or directory "/+mode=text,lrecl=80,recfm=fb" is not found

Here is how I used using the phpseclib library:

```
 define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', NET_SFTP_LOG_COMPLEX);
 $user = 'username';
 $host = 'host';
 $key = new Crypt_RSA();
 $key->loadKey(file_get_contents('file.ppk'));
 $sftp = new Net_SFTP($host);
 if ($sftp->login($user,$key)) {
     echo $sftp->exec('ls /+mode=text,lrecl=80,recfm=fb');
 } else {
     return false;
 }
```

In the above if I try with `$sftp->exec('ls -la');` and `$sftp->exec('pwd');`
it gives me the list of directories present & the current directory respectively.. which means the SFTP connection is fine and the `exec` command works.

But the same throws error when I use the `ls /+mode=text,lrecl=80,recfm=fb` commands as mentioned above.

Is there any other thing that need to be set to make these `/+mode=text.....` commands to work

Answer (score 1):

```
sftp> ls /+mode=text,lrecl=80,recfm=fb
```

The above is OpenSSH `sftp` client command `ls`. Internally, it issues a sequence of SFTP requests (`OPENDIR`, `READDIR`, `CLOSE`) to retrieve a directory listing.

The SFTP server is implemented to treat `OPENDIR` with that unique syntax specifically, as documented in [the article you link to](https://dovetail.com/docs/sftp/using.html).

---

```
echo $sftp->exec('ls /+mode=text,lrecl=80,recfm=fb');
```

While the above executes a remote shell `ls` command. The shell `ls` command does not have a special treatment for the syntax and considers it a path and fails.

Note that while you execute the `exec` on `$sftp` instance, the method is actually implemented in parent `SSH2` class and has nothing to do with SFTP.

---

To emulate the `ls` command of OpenSSH `sftp` (i.e. to send `OPENDIR` SFTP request), use some of the directory listing commands of `SFTP` class, like `nlist` or `rawlist`:

```
$sftp->nlist('/+mode=text,lrecl=80,recfm=fb');
```